# Convert Shapefile to SQL

Tags: sql, gis

I'm trying to convert a shapefile I have to SQL format.

I've tried doing this using `shp2pgsql`, but, alas, this program doesn't read the `SHAPEFILE.prj` file, so I end up with coordinates in an inconvenient format.

Is there a way to convert shapefiles to SQL which respects their PRJ specification?

Comment: Could you show an example of what the records look like? Also the output of `\d the_table name`?

Comment: I personally would read the shape files into R and export them to a sql table.

Answer (score 2):

You may have things in one projection that you want to display or interact with in more familiar values, like longitude and latitude. For example Planet OpenStreetMap uses a spherical mercator and gives you values like this when you ask for text:

```
cal_osm=# select st_astext(way) from planet_osm_point limit 3;
                 st_astext                 
-------------------------------------------
 POINT(-13852634.6464924 4928686.75004766)
 POINT(-13850470.0501262 4930555.55031171)
 POINT(-13850160.8268447 4930880.61375574)
(3 rows)
```

You can use `st_transform` to return a more familiar format like this:

```
cal_osm=# select st_astext(st_transform(way, 4326)) from planet_osm_point limit 3;
                 st_astext                 
-------------------------------------------
 POINT(-124.440334282677 40.4304093953086)
 POINT(-124.42088938268 40.4431868953078)
 POINT(-124.418111582681 40.4454091953076)
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

A prj file is essentially a text file that contains the coordinate system information in the ESRI Well-known-text(WKT) format.  Could you just write a program that uses shp2pgsql to convert the geometries and then store the associated WKT string from the prj?

Of note: The WKT format is an EPSG accepted format for delimiting projected and geographic coordinate system information, but different authorities may have different names for projections or projection parameters.  PostGIS might be different from Oracle which might in turn be different from ESRI.  So if you store the prj's WKT make sure that it is in an esri_coordinate_system column.  PostGIS might have a different naming convention format for parameters.

Also, in case you're interested, there is a C++ open FileGDB api that allows you to access row information without license.  It's available in 32 and 64 bit on windows and linux:

http://resources.arcgis.com/content/geodatabases/10.0/file-gdb-api